Birthdays probability problem
Given $n$ people, the probability of them having distinct birthdays is $\frac{\frac{365!}{\left(365-n\right)!}}{365^n}$. This can be expressed as defining the sample space $\Omega$ to be all ordered $n$-tuples of days, so $|\Omega|=365^n$. As we assume the selection of the people is ordered, there are $\frac{365!}{\left(365-n\right)!}$ options distinct $n$ birthdays, which makes the probability of having $n$ distinct dates be $\frac{365!}{\left(365-n\right)!\cdot365^{n}}$.
However, why must the people be ordered? If they are unordered, we are considering $\frac{365!}{n!\cdot\left(365-n\right)!}$ options for selecting $n$ distinct dates. The total number of unordered dates is $\frac{\left(365+n-1\right)!}{364!\cdot n !}$. Yet, the fraction $\frac{\frac{365!}{n!\cdot\left(365-n\right)!}}{\frac{\left(365+n-1\right)!}{364!\cdot n !}}=\frac{365!\cdot364!\cdot n!}{\left(365+n-1\right)!\cdot\left(365-n\right)!\cdot n!}$ is not the same as $\frac{365!}{\left(365-n\right)!\cdot365^{n}}$. As considering whether the people are "ordered" or not is simply synthetic for me to find the preferable proportions of the events, I'd expect the probabilities to remain the same. After all, the question I'm looking into is: What is the probability that among a group of $n$ people, all will have distinct birthdays? Therefore, the answer should be the same, whether I consider this group as "ordered" or "not".

Well, consider the problem just for tossing a pair of fair dice.  You can consider them as unordered if you like, but then the various cases are not equally probable.  ${2,2}$ is half as likely as ${1,3}$, for example.   With $n$ dice, or $n$ people, the number of cases grows quite fast.

When you express the answer to a combinatorics probability problem as
$$\frac{N}{D},$$
you must have that

$~D~$ represents a sample space of equally likely events.

$~N~$ represents the subset of the sample space, where each element in the subset is regarded as favorable.



To intuitively explain why you must regard order as important, for this particular problem, I will work with much smaller numbers.
Suppose that you are focusing on days of the week, when someone was born, rather than calendar days of the year.
Further assume that each day of the week is equally likely.
Further assume that you wish to compute the probability that $~3~$ random people were born on different days of the week.
The initial computation is
$$\frac{7 \times 6 \times 5}{7^3} = \frac{210}{343} = \frac{30}{49}.$$
Now, lets take a deeper look at each of the $~7^3 = 343~$ possibilities.

Group-1 
You have $~3~$ people, all born on the same day of the week. 
The enumeration here is $~7.~$

Group-2 
You have two people born on one day of the week, and a third born on some other day of the week. 
The enumeration here is $~7 \times 6 \times 3 = 7 \times 18.$

That is, once you identify the $~7~$ ways of choosing the repeated day of the week, and then $~6~$ ways of choosing the solo day of the week, there are $~3~$ ways of ordering the occurrences.  For example, you could have Sunday, Sunday, Monday, or Sunday,Monday,Sunday, or Monday,Sunday,Sunday.

Group-3 
You have $~3~$ people, all born on different days of the week.  The enumeration here is $~7 \times 6 \times 5.$



So, when order is construed as important, you have : Group-1 $~= 7,~$ Group-2 $~= 7 \times 18,~$ Group-3 $~= 7 \times 30.$
Note that the sum of the three groups is
$$7 \times [ ~1 + 18 + 30~] = 7 \times 49 = 7^3,$$
as expected.
Now, watch what happens when you construe order to not be important.
Group-1 is multiplied by the scaling factor of $~\dfrac{1}{1}.$
Group-2 is multiplied by the scaling factor of $~\dfrac{1}{3}.$
Group-3 is multiplied by the scaling factor of $~\dfrac{1}{6}.$
So, superficially you have construed the sample space to be
$$\frac{7}{1} + \frac{7 \times 6 \times 3}{3} + \frac{7 \times 6 \times 5}{6} = 7 + 42 + 35 = 84.$$
Of those $~84~$ possibilities, exactly $~35~$ of them are favorable.
Note that $~\dfrac{35}{84} = \dfrac{5}{12} \neq \dfrac{30}{49}.$
The explanation is that the computation of $~\dfrac{35}{84}~$ is flat wrong, because the sample space of $~84~$ events are not equally likely.
What caused the sample space of $~84~$ events to not be equally likely is that you started with Group-1 $~= 7,~$ Group-2 $~= 7 \times 18,~$ Group-3 $~= 7 \times 30.$
So, the above three groups contained events that were all equally likely.  Then, a different scaling factor (i.e. $~1~$ versus $~\dfrac{1}{3}~$ versus $~\dfrac{1}{6}$) was applied to the events in the three groups.

The approach counting ordered tuples works because every outcome you're counting in the denominator is equally likely. This is not the case when you count distinct multisets (because e.g. $\{1,2,3\}$ is six times as likely as $\{1,1,1\}$), so the ratio $\frac{\text{number of valid multisets}}{\text{number of possible multisets}}$ doesn't give you the correct probability of getting a valid multiset. You could fix this by counting the multisets in groups according to their probability.

Consider flipping two identical and independent fair coins.
What the the probability they show distinct sides (one Heads and one Tails in any order)?

The classic birthday solution says $\dfrac{2!}{\left(2-2\right)!\cdot2^{2}}=\dfrac24$  corresponding to $\frac{|\{HT, TH\}|}{|\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}|}$

You are saying it should be $\dfrac{\frac{2!}{2!\cdot\left(2-2\right)!}}{\frac{\left(2+2-1\right)!}{(2-1)!\cdot 2 !}}=\dfrac13$ corresponding to $\frac{|\{one\,of\,each\}|}{|\{HH,one\,of\,each,TT\}|}$


You could correct your approach to $\frac{\mathbb P(one\,of\,each)}{\mathbb P(HH) +\mathbb P(one\,of\,each) +\mathbb P(TT)}= \frac{\frac12}{\frac14 +\frac12 +\frac14}$ but that would take you back to the classic birthday solution.
